# Verifying a condition for which $\int_\gamma p\ dx + q\ dy$ depends only on endpoints

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

**Hypothesis:**  Suppose there exists a function $U(x,y)$ in $\Omega$ with partial derivatives

$${\partial U \over \partial x} = p \quad \quad {\partial U \over \partial y} = q$$

**Goal:** Show that the integral $\int_\gamma p\ dx + q\ dy$ defined in $\Omega$ depends only on the end points of $\gamma$.

**Ahlfors' Claim:**

$$
\int_\gamma p\ dx + q\ dy = \underbrace{\int_a^b \left( {\partial U \over \partial x} x'(t) + {\partial U \over \partial y} y'(t) \right)dt = \int_a^b {d \over dt} U(x(t), y(t)) dt}_{\text{Question 1: what allows for this step?}}
$$

so that then

$$
\underbrace{\int_a^b {d \over dt} U(x(t), y(t)) dt = U(x(b), y(b)) - U(x(a), y(a))}_{\text{Question 2: Is this something like the fundamental theorem of calculus w/more than one variable?}}
$$

which means that the value of $\int_\gamma p\ dx + q\ dy$ depends only on the end points $x(a) + iy(a)$ and $x(b) + iy(b)$ of $\gamma$.

My two questions are outlined above.

Comment: In question 1 the integrands are equal.  The left integrand is the derivative of U(x(t),y(t)) with respect to t using the chain rule.  In question 2 it is the single variable fundamental theorem, since U(x(t),y(t)) is considered as a function of t only.

Comment: It's the fact that $\left.\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right(U\right) = \frac{\partial U}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial U}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$ thus $\left.\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right(U\right)dt = \frac{\partial U}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial U}{\partial y}dy$.

Comment: Is $U$ a scalar function?

Comment: $U$ is defined on $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ and sends values to $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step in question 1 is the definition of contour integral, the following step is the multivariable chain rule. Question 2 is the regular old fundamental theorem of calculus applied to the function $h(t) := U(x(t),y(t))$.